# Hibernate JPA2.0 and Maven

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa-2.0

I try to build simple app, i want to use spring, wicket and JPA2.0 (Hibernate). To put all of those together I use maven. And I have problem with hibernate. Below is my pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>comicsTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>comicsTest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
     <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hiberante</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <modules>
  </modules>
  <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

and all I get is

```
27.12.10 12:41:44 CET: Refreshing [/comicsTest/pom.xml]
27.12.10 12:41:48 CET: Downloaded https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/hiberante/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.0.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.pom
27.12.10 12:41:48 CET: [WARN] The POM for org.hiberante:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.0.Final is missing, no dependency information available
27.12.10 12:41:50 CET: Downloaded https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/hiberante/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.0.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar
27.12.10 12:41:50 CET: Missing artifact org.hiberante:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.0.Final:compile
```

And above URLs are correct and file is there :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`org.hibernate` is misspelt in your pom as `org.hiberante.`